# Nested divs with absolute positioning causing overflow problems

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an absolutely positioned parent div that contains a header div and a resizable body div as shown below. The body div contains a content div and an absolutely positioned child.

When the body is resized, I need

1. Content that overflows the parent div to be hidden
2. The body div to show scroll bars if its content (the combination of the content div and the child div) exceeds the dimensions of the body.

The example show does the first part, but the scroll bars only appear when the body height is smaller than the content height, rather than appearing when part of the the child div is hidden by the parent boundary.

Is there a solution to this in either pure CSS or involving some javascript?

```html
<div id="parent" style="overflow:hidden;position: absolute; left: 50px; top: 50px; border-width: 1px; border-color: black; border-style: solid;">
    <div id="header" style="border-color: red; border-width: 1px; border-style: solid;">
        <p>No scroll bars in header</p>
    </div>
    <div id="body" style="width: 300px; height: 250px; border-width: 1px; border-color: blue; border-style: solid; overflow: auto; resize: both;">
        <div id="content" style="border-width: 1px; border-color: grey; border-style: solid;">
            <p>Content</p>
            <p>Content</p>
            <p>Content</p>
            <p>Content</p>
        </div>
        <div id="child" style="position:absolute; top:200px;left:100px;width: 50px; height: 50px; border-width: 1px; border-color: green; border-style: solid;"
            <p>Child</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the child's position to `relative`. Having `absolute` position means it is not concidering anything from the html. It is kind of like using the god mode. Having `relative` means it will concider its parent position. In this case, it is the div `#body`

I have adjusted the top and left values also because it was positioning the child `200px` away from the content position after changing the position to relative.

**Here is the working code.** *And please... use CSS instead of the attribute* `style=""` 
*This way, you will clear your html code and it'll be easier to read, write and debug.*

```css
#parent {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
}

#header {
  border-color: red;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
}

#body {
  width: 200px;
  height: 170px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: blue;
  border-style: solid;
  overflow: auto;
  resize: both;
}

#content {
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: grey;
  border-style: solid;
}

#child {
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  left: 30px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: green;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="header">
    <p>No scroll bars in header</p>
  </div>
  <div id="body">
    <div id="content">
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
    </div>
    <div id="child">
      <p>Child</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the very quick answer! Using relative positioning will have other implications for the real code, but I can work that out. 

As for your comment about using CSS, I find that short snippets of code are easier to understand if everything is inline. However, I agree with your suggestion for production code, and accept that my use of `style` in this case is a personal preference.

Comment: Ha! I spoke too soon. My real code uses https://jsplumb.github.io/jsplumb/dragging.html to implement dragging on the `parent` and `child` divs. And the documentation in the "Required CSS" sections states that "You must set position:absolute on elements that you intend to be draggable". However, you answered the question as posed, so your answer stands. I'll investigate alternatives to jsplumb that provide all the functionality I need.

Comment: I've discovered another flaw when applying the solution to the real problem: the parent div could itself be a child of another parent, and so it needs `position:relative`. However, that then messes up the width of the parent.

Comment: If you need help with that I recommmend that you post another question while leaving this one as it is as this could help people that has the same overflow problem in a parent container. In the other question, make sure you provide enough code to reproduce your problem like you did here. It'll insure that your question(s) are not too broad and it will help more people in the end. :)

Answer (score 0):

when you give absolute position, the element is positioned relative to its first positioned (not static) ancestor element. And in your case the parent is not positioned or it's positioned static. So the child will be positioned relative to the viewport. If you want the child to be positioned relative to the parent (body), you have to make the parent position relative.

```
<div id="body" style="position:relative; width: 300px; height: 250px; border-width: 1px; border-color: blue; border-style: solid; overflow: auto; resize: both;">
```